# maven-archetype-webapp project not seen in ("Add and remove..." in server popup.)

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, maven

i created a maven project with artefactId maven-archetype-webapp .When i want to add it to tomcat ("Add and remove..." in server popup.) i don't see the project in the given list 
Is there a soluion or should i create another project with a new artefactId if it's a yes what is the name of the artefact

Answer (score 0):

i used this command to convert my project o make it support Eclipse’s wtp
 `mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0`